# Quantization of energy of phonons

Tags: photons, lattice-model, phonons

when taking into account of energy of photons, the relationship $E=nh\nu$ stands because it is said that the Energy is proportional to the frequency of the electromagnetic wave, however when the energy of a phonon is considered, the energy relationship is written as 
$E=(n+\frac{1}{2})h{\nu}_E$. Is there some mathematics that can account for this formula or some literature at least? 
The text I am studying says that it is because even as zero kelvin there has to be some energy stored in the lattice, which is in itself not an argument, moreover how can I be certain that the stored energy will be $\frac{1}{2}h\nu_E$

Comment: Regarding the photon, where does the $n$ in $E=n h \nu$ comes from? Why  not just $E=  h \nu$, see e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photon_energy

Answer (score 2):

In quantum treatment, phonons are quantum harmonic oscillators, which is studied in any quantum mechanics textbooks. The energy spectrum is readily studied there.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_harmonic_oscillator

The $1/2\hbar\nu_E$ comes from uncertainty principle. (A quantum harmonic oscillator is confined in space so its momentum cannot be zero)

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncertainty_principle